# Iterating through a JSON string in Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I am hosting a web server which exposes the REST APIs. following is the JSON response that I get from the server.

```
[
{
    "score": 4,
    "sense": "be the winner in a contest or competition; be victorious; \"He won the Gold Medal in skating\"; \"Our home team won\"; \"Win the game\""
},
{
    "score": 2,
    "sense": "win something through one's efforts; \"I acquired a passing knowledge of Chinese\"; \"Gain an understanding of international finance\""
},
{
    "score": 0,
    "sense": "obtain advantages, such as points, etc.; \"The home team was gaining ground\"; \"After defeating the Knicks, the Blazers pulled ahead of the Lakers in the battle for the number-one playoff berth in the Western Conference\""
},
{
    "score": 4,
    "sense": "attain success or reach a desired goal; \"The enterprise succeeded\"; \"We succeeded in getting tickets to the show\"; \"she struggled to overcome her handicap and won\""
    }
]
```

I want to display this in list. I am using material design, in the following manner:

```
<md-list data-ng-repeat="item in sensesscores track by $index">
    <md-item-content>
    <div class="md-tile-content">
        {{item.sense}}
    </div>
    <div class="md-tile-left">
        {{item.score}}
    </div>
    </md-item-content>

</md-list>
```

In my controller, I have the following:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/nlp-wsd-demo/wsd/disambiguate').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.sensesscores = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I made sure that I am able to get the data in 'sensesscores' and also printed it on the screen. However, I am not able to make parse and display it the list. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

---

I changed the code to correct the syntax and moving the ng-repeat up the heirarchy, but it still doesnt work. However, I tried it on a different JSON file, which works.

```
[{
"sense": "sensaS,NF,ASNGD.,AD., BVAS.,GMDN,FG e1",
"score" : 5
},
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 13
}
,
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 1
},
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 0
},
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 3
},
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 2
},
{
"sense": "sen ASG SFG S H D GD FJDF JDF J GFJ FDFGse2",
"score" : 1
}
]
```

I dont understand whats wrong with the JSON response.

Comment: i would like to note that the ng-repeat should be one level in hierarchy above the item items, they will never show up this way, move them one level down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. The content needed to be converted to json object and I did that using jquery - $.parseJSON(data)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has many typos, the below is formatted correctly:

```
<md-list>
    <md-item data-ng-repeat="item in sensesscores track by $index">
       <md-item-content>
         <div class="md-tile-content">
            {{item.sense}}
         </div>
         <div class="md-tile-left">
            {{item.score}}
         </div>
       </md-item-content> // this tag was not closed, but rather a new opener
   </md-item>
</md-list> // this tag was not closed properly, missing ">"
```

Change it, and your data will show as you expect.